# How to edit a read-only document in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, read-only

I need to fill a form (which I received in .doc format and saved as .odt). The file is read-only except for the fields where I can enter the information. Unfortunately, with the fields filled it doesn't fit on one page, and I need to edit it so I can print and submit it.

With LibreOffice beta 3, I could edit anything outside of the fields, and the fonts were slightly smaller, so it fit on the page even with the fields filled. Today I upgraded LibreOffice, and when I opened to edit a field where I had a mistake, it no longer fits on the page, and I can't edit it. When I opened the properties it says that the document is NOT read-only, but it is. When I try to delete text it tells me that I can't edit the read-only content.

Can anyone give me some advice, because I've been trying to print my form for 2 hours already.

I tried AbiWord and KWord, but both are missing elements from the page (though the forms fit). I can also edit the margins (Format -> Page is dimmed, but when I begin to edit a field it's no longer dimmed)med

Comment: I also encountered inconsistent handling of encryptied .doc files. So far, the only help I could find was this link. Unfortunately it requires Word. http://itmanager.blogs.com/notes/2005/04/how_to_crack_un.html If the script editor does not work, you might do this: 1. In Word open protected .doc 2. export to word xml 2003 format
3. edit xml file to remove protected tag 4. reopen xml in word and save .doc
5. import to Libreoffice.

Comment: I don't have privileges in Stack Exchange to write an answer, so, I'm answering as comment: I  solved this issue with context menu over the read-only form in the document, then clicked the "edit section..." option, then, on the dialog box, untick the "Protect" option, click ok and the form is editable.

Answer (score 5):

You have to turn "Design mode On" in order to make changes on the document.

Enable the form toolbar through the option *View -> Toolbars -> Form Design* in the main menu, and the button for toggling [design mode on/off](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Design_Mode_On_Off) appears.

Comment: How, pray do you do that?

Comment: This has no effect for me.

Comment: This has no effect for me.

Comment: Does not work in my case either

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar problem, trying to edit a `.doc` file, and activating "Design Mode On" didn't help it.

I was able to edit it only after saving it as a `Word 97/2000/XP/2003 (.doc)` and then doing a sequence of disabling and enabling again edit again, through clicking the button "Edit File" (in the default toolbar, sits at right of the *Send Document as E-Mail*).

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by :

```
File -> Save a Copy...
```

Turns out the copy .doc file is not read-only.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't work for me, strange.

Comment: The saved document has the same read only characteristic, for me.

Comment: Also does not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I ended up using Word 2007 as I was unable to work out how to do this in LibreOffice.

Locked text like this can be due to Word "Forms". Copying from [Unlocking Forms in Word 2007](http://help.lockergnome.com/office/UNLOCKING-FORMS-WORD-2007--ftopict932726.html):

> Go to the `Quick Access Toolbar > More Commands > Commands not in the Ribbon` - scroll down to `Lock` - add to your Quick Access Toolbar
>
> and - amazing - the Padlock IS now available to use on a Fill-in Form just like in Word 2003 - just click to unlock and click again to re-lock your form!

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me, and none of these either: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/37966/read-only-content-cannot-be-changed-no-modifications-will-be-accepted/

Someone should write a crack for LibreOffice.